# Use Cordova Plugin in Angular 2 + Cordova app

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugins

I have an Angular 2 app, that I'm building into cordova and deploying to Android/IOS. I'm NOT using ionic, I've seen a number of solutions that use ionic but I can't convert this entire project to ionic now.

So far everything has worked fine, except I can't figure out how to use the cordova plugins.  Specifically I'm trying to use 'cordova-plugin-file' to store local files on the device.

I can't figure out how to import/access plugin files or functions? I may be missing something with how cordova plugins work. Most tutorials show just using whatever the plugin added functionality wise like for example..

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
   console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
   createFile(fs.root, "newTempFile.txt", false);
}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

However the above code breaks angular 2 and I get errors like this.

```
 Property 'requestFileSystem' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

It's pretty obvious that somethings not getting imported or reverenced correctly.  Most likely because cordova is a sub-folder of the angular 2 app. And I run ng build and put the output files into the cordova folder, so at that time it's unaware of cordova?

```
 Angular_2_project
 ├── cordova
 │   └── plugins
 ├── src
 │   └── index.html
 │   └── app
 │        └── html/ts files
```

Comment: is cordova.js loaded ?

Comment: Probably not, I guess that may be my question how do you load cordova.js into angular 2? is it just a script reference in index.html?

Comment: Yess..!! Thats the only option. If its angular cli project then add in angular cli.json. this is causing the error fr u

Comment: It is an angular cli project. Do you add cordova.js to "app": [{ "scripts": ["path/to/script/cordova.js"]...  And do I just need cordova.js or the plugin files?

Comment: yes, need to add in scripts & Adding both cordova.js & plugin files.

Comment: Awesome thanks! That makes much more sense. I'll test it out this afternoon and report back.

Comment: Sure :) Plz check answer.

Comment: check this solution also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397322/3600674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems cordova.js is not loaded.

Add cordova.js & Plugin related .js

If it's angular-cli.json just load them up in scripts.

Also when you will add it in your *.ts files, it will throw an error while trans 
when u will try to build it.
To avoid that add it in declare at beginning of your *.ts file.

Example :
i want to use cordova.on in my ts file.

I will just write

```
declare var cordova:any
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!  It does cause some issues running in the browser though. Which is slightly to be expected.  It would also be nice to have typescript enabled for those cordova plugins, but that's a different question

Comment: You are welcomed. Let me know which issues. There will be issues for sure, because only angular 2 and cordova is a very strange combination indeed

Comment: Hi Andrew Barta and Parth Ghiya, I have facing the same issue, I adding the device plugin. I decleared device : any; but while running it in browser it throws device not found exception. please let me suggest for some solution or please share for some tutorial to follow

Comment: maybe post another question with more details.  There's a lot of things cordova related that don't work in the browser, at least without out some coercion, try deploying to a device and see if the error goes away.